# Why always i clear route and cached route when new created?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8 and I am facing issue with route. When I create a route it does not appear in route list after running below command

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

I get all route. How can i solve it. Why i run these command for new routes?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#optimizing-route-loading):

**Optimizing Route Loading**

> If you are building a large application with many routes, you should
> make sure that you are running the `route:cache` Artisan command during
> your deployment process:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

> This command reduces all of your route registrations into a single
> method call within a cached file, improving the performance of route
> registration when registering hundreds of routes.

You should only run `php artisan route:cache` during deployment, while you develop locally you shouldn't cache your routes, otherwise new routes that you create wont be registered until you run `php artisan route:clear` or `php artisan route:cache` again.

```
php artisan route:cache
// clears the route cache and then re caches the routes

php artisan route:clear
// clears the route cache
```